# Understanding the inductive proof about field extension in Artin

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

This is a proposition in Artin's algebra. But I cannot understand the proof of (b) clearly. Could someone tell me how does he jump from the third step to the fourth step? Thanks so much[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr68T.png)

Comment: Maybe insert $\ldots =F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{k-1})(\alpha_k)=\ldots$ [and the final $\alpha_{\color{red} n}$ instead of $\alpha_{\color{red} k}$ is clearly a typo]

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Yes, it is. But I still don't understead the final step. How does the conclusion come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F(a_1,...,a_{k-1})=F'$ is a field.
Thus $F(a_1,...,a_{k-1})[a_k]=F'[a_k]$ and you can reapply a) slightly modified with $F'$ instead of $F$